# Add an image to to CAShapeLayer within its bezierpath

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, cashapelayer

I am trying to implement 
https://github.com/joshdhenry/SpinWheelControl library in my app, where for each wheel slice I am trying to add a custom image to its shapelayer, or any other way possible inside the slice to its bounds and path, I am not being able to do so. I tried adding the image to the content of a new shapelayer and added it to my pie slice, but it didn't work either.

```
for wedgeNumber in 0..<numberOfWedges {
        let wedge: SpinWheelWedge = source.wedgeForSliceAtIndex(index: wedgeNumber)

        //Wedge shape
        wedge.shape.configureWedgeShape(index: wedgeNumber, radius: radius, position: spinWheelCenter, degreesPerWedge: degreesPerWedge)
        wedge.layer.addSublayer(wedge.shape)

        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.contents = UIImage(named: "sample.jpg")?.cgImage
        layer.bounds = wedge.shape.bounds
        layer.path = wedge.shape.path
        wedge.shape.addSublayer(layer)


        spinWheelView.addSubview(wedge)
    }
```

Output in simulator:

[image: Output in simulator]

Why am I not being able to add image  to the shape layer??

Needed output

[image: needed output]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Briefly, you need a `CALayer` for the image and a `CAShapeLayer` for the wedge path. Use the shape layer as the mask for the image layer.

Comment: I made a maskLayer with needed cgpath and masked my imageLayer(CALayer), then added the imageLayer to my wedge(UIVIew) as a sublayer. Still the image is not visible in the slice

Comment: Check your bounds on the image layer. It's not the same as frame and may be moving the image outside the viewable area. Plus, set a breakpoint after you add the image and check what the debugger in Xcode can show you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class CustomImageView: UIImageView{ 

var bezierPath = UIBezierPath()

override func setNeedsLayout() {
    bezierPath.reversing()
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.frame = self.bounds
    shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = shapeLayer
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
}

}
```

your modified code

```
for wedgeNumber in 0..<numberOfWedges {
    let wedge: SpinWheelWedge = source.wedgeForSliceAtIndex(index: wedgeNumber)

    //Wedge shape
    wedge.shape.configureWedgeShape(index: wedgeNumber, radius: radius, position: spinWheelCenter, degreesPerWedge: degreesPerWedge)
    wedge.layer.addSublayer(wedge.shape)

    let imageLayer = CustomImageView()
    imageLayer.image = UIImage(named: "sample.jpg")
    imageLayer.bezierPath = wedge.shape.path
    imageLayer.setNeedsLayout()

    // Here you will get an image view with specified path 
       you can subview this imageLayer to the required view
}
```

Comment: you should subview that imageLayer

Comment: @AshwinShrestha Can u share your sample project so i can check on it.

Comment: Thanks, Shezad... I was able to do it by masking my image view with a shape same bezierpath as that of wedge shape.

Comment: @AshwinShrestha hello. can you share your image solution for this?